# Group two rows into one in TOAD data point

Tags: sql, oracle, toad, toad-data-point

My current result set is below:

```
Case_ID    |   Action_name    |   Status_code

1             John                  Valid

1             Peter                 Valid
```

I want this to be

```
Case_ID      |    Action_name   |    Status_Code

1              John, Peter              Valid
```

or it can also be displayed as

```
Case_ID       |  Action_name1   |   Action_name2   |   Status_code

1                   John               peter              Valid
```

Any possible information would be greatly helpful. I tried the Pivot function but for some reasons, I couldn't get it right. I know we can do this in SQL server but I'm new to TOAD data point.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify database you use. If it is Oracle, then LISTAGG function might help:

```
SQL> -- This is your current output:
SQL> with test (case_id, action_name, status_Code) as
  2     (select 1, 'John', 'valid' from dual union all
  3      select 1, 'Peter', 'valid' from dual
  4     )
  5  -- Adjust it using this:
  6  select
  7    case_id,
  8    listagg(action_name, ', ') within group (order by action_name) action_name,
  9    status_code
 10  from test
 11  group by case_id, status_code;

   CASE_ID ACTION_NAME                    STATU
---------- ------------------------------ -----
         1 John, Peter                    valid

SQL>
```

Otherwise, see whether your database offers such an *aggregation* function; I know some of them do.

Comment: I did encounter an error while I was running this. the name John appeared twice. Some rows display the result as John, john, peter instead of John, peter. Not sure why.

Comment: I don't know either. If you could prepare CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data, I'd be able to look at it.